# python: how to select specific values in a column and make them into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

here is the sample data frame

```
year    month  
2011    1

2012    1

2013    1

2011    2

2011    3

2013    2
```

I want to select `year > 2012` and make it a new column "new year".

Comment: And what would be in the new column?

Comment: sorry i meant a new table. so the new table contains year>2012 and month

Comment: Try to solve the problem yourself first, then show us the code and ask a specific question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making `new_year == True`, then you can do the following.

```
df['new_year'] = df['year'] > 2012
```

You end up with:

```
year  month  new_year
2011    1    False
2012    1    False
2013    1    True
2011    2    False
```

Obviously you can have what ever you want in these columns:

```
bananas = 'bananas'
else_grapes = 'grapes'

df['new_year'] = np.where(df['year']>2012, bananas, else_grapes)

year  month  new_year
2011    1    'grapes'
2012    1    'grapes'
2013    1    'bananas'
2011    2    'grapes'
```

Comment: Why use `np.where` at all?  Isn't that just `df['year'] > 2012`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you're looking for:

```
new_df = df[df['year'] > 2012]
```